# Set prior for logistic regression in R when using unequal group sizes (29 versus 48 cases)

Tags: regression, logistic, prior, bayes

I have 29 cases for negative outcome (0) and 48 cases for positive outcome (1). I fit my data with logistic regression model

```
LogisticReg <- glm(Y~A+B+C, family = binomial(), data = d)
```

Then I have large set of observations (~800) that I want to classify using this model.

```
LogisticProb <- predict(LogisticReg, newdata = myTable, type="response")
```

Now I take a look at probabilities and classify <=0.5 to one group and >0.5 to the second group. However, this doesn't take into account unequal sizes of two groups in my training data. I need to incorporate this prior information, presumably using Naive Bayesian classifier.

I took a look at **weights** argument for glm and verified that **LogisticReg$prior.weights** right now gives equal weights for all observations, however I am still not sure how to implement this prior. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to correct for different sizes of your two "groups"? That will be the case for any logistic regression in which the two outcomes aren't equally probable over the population of interest. And, since this seems to be a classification problem, have you considered classification methods other than logistic regression?

Comment: My two outcomes should be roughly equally probable, but the training data I have is not (29 versus 48 cases). I am afraid I am biasing my model towards more abundant class. I tried also random forest which gave me similar error rate. I would like to stick with logistic regression because it's easier for people to interpret.

Comment: Any idea why your "training data" ended up so weighted toward positive outcomes? If outcomes over the entire population are about equally probable, that raises the unpleasant possibility that your training data are not representative of the underlying population in some important ways. That problem might not be "fixed" by a weighting scheme.

Comment: @EdM Good point. This is because it is harder to obtain data for 0 outcome in the training set. This is dataset from molecular biology/genomics and unfortunately technology is not advanced enough to make it easier. I am hoping this doesn't bias my dataset, but there is no way to know.